# Wysiwyg editor for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-wysiwyg5-rails

I use bootstrap-wysiwyg5-rails as a wysiwyg editor on my web page. After setting up my page I am not able to run insert link and insert image. I use bootstrap 3 wip version. I have no error in firebug on running page. When I click insert link/image modal does not appear. Only screen freezes

Comment: Does this also happen when you directly load that page the wysiwyg editor is placed on, and do you use turbolinks?

Comment: Yes I use turbolinks and this also does not work when loading page directly

Comment: Couldyou provide a jsfiddle? I think guessing does not lead us to anywhere, and your question is lacking code. (Update the question with the fiddle link)